# Make a php script to sleep until 8:00 in the morning

Tags: php, sleep

I have a php script which starts execution at 7:57. It does a http request. Once the http request is over, I want the script to sleep until 8:00. How to achieve this in PHP ?

Comment: Once the request is complete, you can have the script stopped anyway. What would you like to do after 8:00 ?

Answer (score 5):

Use time_sleep_until()

```
bool time_sleep_until ( float $timestamp )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is to schedule it with cron. If you just want it running 24/7 for the heck of it, http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're running via CLI och WEB, but CLI is recommended for this.

The easiest way is to use [time_sleep_until](http://php.net/time_sleep_until). Another way to do it is to sleep while the current hour is less than 8, like:

```
while(date('H') < 8)) {
    sleep(50);
}

// Hour is 8, do your work
```